# Как сравнить 2 объекта

Tags: java

Как без лапша-кода сравнить 2 объекта?

Например такой класс

```
public class MyObject{
    String name;
    String surname;
    int age;
    boolean isAlive;
}
```

и чтобы не писать что-то типа

```
boolean isEquals(Myobject o1, Myobject o2) {
    if (!o1.name.equals(o2.name)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!o1.surname.equals(o2.surname)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (o1.age != (o2.age)) {
        return false;
    }
    return o1.isAlive == o2.isAlive;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.util.Objects;

if(Objects.equals(o1, o2)) {
 todo
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно переопределить метод `Object::equals()`.

Вы можете автоматически сделать это через IntelliJ IDEA:
`Code -> Generate -> equals and hashcode`.

У вас должно получиться что-то похожее на это:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    MyObject myObject = (MyObject) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, myObject.name) &&
            Objects.equals(surname, myObject.surname) &&
            age == myObject.age
            isAlive == myObject.isAlive;
}
```

Можно будет сравнивать так:

`myObject1.equals(myObject2);`

Comment: Собственно тут и получается лапша-код, только немного иначе выглядит. К тому же вопрос не стоял в том, чтобы переопределить стандартный `equals()`, у меня свой метод `isEquals()`

Comment: @Dred по другому сделать нельзя. Только рефлексия. А зачем нужен свой метод вместо `equals()`?

Comment: Ваш метод кстати хуже сгенерированного идеей

Comment: это нужно, чтобы не переопределять изначальный `equals` Мне, например, необходимо сравнивать не по всем полям, что есть в объекте.

Comment: @Dred так удалите пару полей)). Ну тогда самый лучший вариант - с компаратором

Answer (score 3):

```
Comparator<MyObject> comparator = Comparator.comparing(MyObject::getName)
                                            .thenComparing(MyObject::getSurname)
                                            .thenComparing(MyObject::isAlive)
                                            .thenComparingInt(MyObject::getAge);

Comparator<MyObject> nullSafe = Comparator.nullsFirst(comparator);

return nullSafe.compare(o1, o2) == 0;
```

Comment: А Comparator можно использовать с объектами которые не наследуют Comparable?

Comment: @Dred да, можно.

Comment: @Dred то есть вот это не лапша код, а то, что у нас с Антоном Сорокиным - лапша-код? Вдобавок, этот код гораздо медленнее.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev а что делать, если одно из полей - `List`?

Comment: @ИмяФамилия естественно определить логику сравнения списков. Например `.thenComparing(MyObject::getList, (a, b) -> a.equals(b) ? 0 : 1)`

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev ок, понял, просто `String` имплементит `Comparable`, а `List` - нет.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, в итоге ваш вариант не подходит если будет какой-то объект нулевым. так как при входе в компаратор видим `default Comparator<T> thenComparing(Comparator<? super T> other) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(other);
        return (Comparator<T> & Serializable) (c1, c2) -> {
            int res = compare(c1, c2);
            return (res != 0) ? res : other.compare(c1, c2);
        };
    }` условие которого не выполняется

Comment: @Dred у вас `nullSafe.compare(null, o2)` возвращает 0?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev, он возвращает NullPointerException, например,если в метод передать `nullsafe.compare(null, new MyObject())`

Comment: @Dred код из моего ответа не может этого делать. Для этого в нём как раз строка `Comparator.nullsFirst(comparator)`.

Comment: @Dred https://ideone.com/i7BcGU

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev https://ideone.com/obGMOf

Comment: @Dred это крайне легко решается. В одну строчку. Если для вас это не очевидно, то пожалуй стоит остановиться на выбранном вами ответе.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev Если вы про [это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23908426/9719337) то это не особенно очевидно :-)

Answer (score 3):

Если хочется универсальный метод, то можно как-то так, рефлекшеном, но Вы наверняка сами знаете, что это медленно и все такое:

```
private static boolean eq(Object o1, Object o2) {
    try {
        if (o1 == null && o2 == null) return true;
        if (o1 == null || o2 == null) return false;
        if (!o1.getClass().equals(o2.getClass())) return false;
        for (Field field : o1.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            Object v1 = field.get(o1);
            Object v2 = field.get(o2);
            if (v1 == null && v2 == null) continue;
            if (v1 == null || v2 == null) return false;
            if (!v1.equals(v2)) return false;
        }
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

PS: В целом не рекомендую использовать такой подход, уж лучше сгенерировать метод через `ide`

Comment: и конечно же для обоаботки вложенных не примитивных типов он не походит

Comment: `o1.getClass().equals(o2.getClass())` можно заменить на `o1 instanceof o2`, вдобавок, второе предотвращает NPE, а первое - нет.

Comment: `o1 instanceof o2` так не бывает, можно с классом сравнить но не с объектом, а вот `npe` на входе надо починить

Answer (score 2):

С помощью библиотеки [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html) и рефлексии можно даже в одну строчку

```
return new EqualsBuilder().reflectionEquals(o1, o2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вам нужно сравнивать объекты, в них нужно переопределять метод `equals()`.

```java
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (!(o instanceof MyObject)) return false;
    MyObject that = (MyObject) o;
    return isAlive == that.isAlive &&
            age == that.age &&
            name.equals(that.name) &&
            surname.equals(that.surname);
}
```

Comment: Не обязательно. Вам могу ответить аналогично как и AntonSorokin

Comment: @Dred вам я тоже могу ответить аналогично тому, как вам ответил Антон Сорокин.